# "(null)" Would like to send you notifications with iOS 9 / Xcode 7

Tags: ios

With Xcode 6 and iOS8 when my app first runs the OS displays a "My App Name Would Like to Send You Notifications" dialog.
However with Xcode 7 / iOS 9 that has changed to ""(null)" Would Like to Send You Notifications".

How do I rectify this?

[When the OS displays the dialog asking if the user will permit location access to the app, then the OS correctly displays the App name in the dialog and not "(null)"]

Comment: Having same issue with iOS9 - However I cant click Don't Allow/OK

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like we have a new property in the info.plist:

`Bundle display name` The key is: `CFBundleDisplayName`

This was blank, but once I set it to `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` I got the right notification permission popup.

Note, I still do see "(null) - Deployment" for one of the categories names in Build Settings for my target

Comment: any fix for the deployment one?